# How to set LC_NUMERIC to English permanently?

Tags: command-line, locale

I need to change `LC_NUMERIC` to English (I have Ubuntu in Spanish) because of the dots and the commas, but if I use `LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"` when I exit the terminal and I open it again, `LC_NUMERIC`is again in Spanish.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried `update-locale LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Append the value to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
echo 'export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"' >>~/.bashrc
```

To make it applicable from the current session of `bash`, `source` the `~/.bashrc` file:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

**Example:** Here i am changing from `en_US.UTF-8` to `C`:

```
$ locale | grep LC_NUMERIC
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"

$ echo 'export LC_NUMERIC="C"' >>~/.bashrc

$ source ~/.bashrc 

$ locale | grep LC_NUMERIC
LC_NUMERIC=C
```

**This will change the `locale` for only the user running the command, for system wide change you need to add the value to `/etc/default/locale`, check the added portion below.**

---

You can also add the value to the systmwide `locale` file, `/etc/default/locale`, which will be read at start. To put it there:

```
echo 'LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"' | sudo tee -a /etc/default/locale
```

Or

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "LC_NUMERIC=\"en_US.UTF-8\"" >>/etc/default/locale'
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works perfectly, I installed Ubuntu one week ago and I am trying to figure out everything, really useful answer!

Comment: @Maria Glad i could help and of course welcome to the Ubuntu world !!

Comment: You sure about that second command?  Your echo will run as root, but the redirection is the current user, and that probably will not have acces to /etc/default/locale

Comment: @Stephen The redirection (and `echo`) is running in a subshell (spawned by `bash -c`), not in the current shell, check the single quotes around.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I didn't see the single quotes.  You're absolutely right.

Comment: Did not work when I only changed /etc/default/locale and logged out then in. Worked when changed ~/.bashrc and /etc/default/locale and restarted computer. Don't have time to test all possible combinations.
Tested with the calculator on a Ubuntu 18.04 system which was shipped with French locale, needed the decimal separator to be a dot because I often copy results from the calculator to other programs or web apps, which only understand the decimal point.

Comment: @heemayl Is there a way to change LC_NUMERIC while running a script only without having to change the basic or locale files so that's it's kind of only for the current script I am running?

Comment: @Tak Yes, you can use e.g. `LC_NUMERIC=C script.sh`, which will set the variable only for that one command (or script in this case).

Answer (score 3):

The "official" technique to change locale settings for number formatting system-wide is:

```
sudo update-locale LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
```

After that, restart your system.

If it still does not work, then probably your graphical desktop environment overwrites the system-wide locale settings. On a personal computer, it is best to configure it so that it does not modify the system-wide locale settings at all. How to do this depends on the desktop environment you use. I made [instructions for LXQt](https://askubuntu.com/a/1251589) for this.

***Source:*** A [comment by Ron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724338/how-to-set-lc-numeric-to-english-permanently#comment1071879_724338) above. I wanted to turn it into a proper answer as it's the official and most straight-forward technique.

Answer (score 1):

Graphical logins do not read shell startup files ( `~/.bashrc`,  `~/.profile` and so on ) by default and also should not because these are bash specific.

So it is better to use `/etc/environment` for system wide environment settings and `~/.xsessionrc` for user specific settings.

PAM should by default read `/etc/environment` - check that

```
/etc/pam.d/login /etc/pam.d/sshd /etc/pam.d/su /etc/pam.d/cron
```

includes the line

```
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1
```

-> https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: _Graphical logins do not read shell startup files ( ~/.bashrc, ~/.profile and so on )_, and what about the login shell?