# Dot versus comma

Tags: keyboard

I'm a new UBUNTU user (version 16.04 LTS). I'm from Brazil and my keyboard is configured as Brazilian Portuguese (ABNT2). I want to change the dot key of numeric keyboard (laptop SAMSUNG NP500R5H-XD2BR). The key is configured for comma... I've tried to follow these steps:

[Set LC_NUMERIC to English permanently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724338/how-to-set-lc-numeric-to-english-permanently)

```
$ locale | grep LC_NUMERIC
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
$ echo 'export LC_NUMERIC="C"' >>~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc    
$ locale | grep LC_NUMERIC
LC_NUMERIC=C
```

So that succeeded, but the situation doesn't change... Is there something else I can do?

Comment: Your locale is already English (`en.US`) so will be the same as `C` locale. Do you want to use Brazilian Portuguese locale?

Comment: Zanna, my first shot to change the numeric format (on the numeric keyboard, comma --> dot) was change for the English locale... it didn't work. After that, i tried the script above and again it didn't work!

Comment: So first your locale was `pt_BR` and you changed to `en.US`?

Comment: Yes, because de pt_BR pattern is comma as decimal separator... Actually, i realized the problem is the samsung keyboard design... the same problem occurs in win10 SO...

Comment: I was going to say I think it's your keyboard layout rather than locale - have you played around with that?

Comment: I've tried. I change the configurations in System < Keyboard... I checked de keyboard configuration file ($  sudo gedit /etc/default/keyboard) and change everything that was possible for me (based on my linux's knowledge). But it's ok .I'm so glad for your attention and kindness. I'll kepp trying!

Comment: Yes, of course!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (as root):

```
locale-gen pt_BR.UTF-8
echo 'LANG="pt_BR.UTF-8"\nLC_ALL="pt_BR.UTF-8"' > /etc/default/locale
```

And reboot...

Comment: `LC_ALL` should be unset... and `/etc/default/locale` is generated by `update-locale` and should only contain `LANG` and `LANGUAGE`

Comment: LC_ALL just overrides LC_*. I know update-locale generates /etc/default/locale, but in the end it is just a script with some checking, the overall result is the same. I use this code to initialize my ubuntu docker server images and it works fine.

Comment: I can't remember exactly why, but just setting LANG & LANGUAGE didn't work for me and I had to set LC_* (and later changed to LC_ALL) in order to work properly. I created this script in a 14.04 server and now I'm using in 16.04 servers.

Comment: Hmm after generating the locale and updating `LANG` & `LANGUAGE` it shouldn't be necessary to set `LC_*`... I never had that problem. But I guess no harm to set it there : S

Comment: Thanks Vinicius. I'm quite sure the the problem is the samsung's keyboard config...

Comment: What is the output of the command `localectl`?

Comment: System Locale: LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
                  LANGUAGE=pt_BR:pt:en
       VC Keymap: n/a
      X11 Layout: br
       X11 Model: pc105