# How to unset the Locale in LXQt?

Tags: lubuntu, locale, lxqt

I have always had problems with locale settings overriding one another. So now, to keep things simple, I want my user under LXQt to simply use the system-wide locale settings and not override anything.

How can that be done?

Comment: If you upgraded from Lubuntu 18.04, you may have things in the `~/.pam_environment` file. In that case you should delete that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Instructions

1. Go to "Start menu → Preferences → LXQt settings → Locale". (Or just start `lxqt-config-locale`)
2. Under "Region:", select the upmost entry "No change".
3. Click "Close" and confirm to save the new settings.
4. Go to "Start menu → Preferences → LXQt settings → Session Settings" (or just start `lxqt-config-locale`) and in section "Environment (Advanced)" make sure that no locale-related environment variables are set here: `LANG`, `LANGUAGE` and any `LC_*` variables.

### Result

Your `~/.config/lxqt/lxqt-config-locale.conf` will now look like this, omitting any locale setting there at all:

```
[General]
__userfile__=false
```

Together with not overwriting locale-related environment variables in the session, this means that the system-wide settings from `/etc/default/locale` will now be taken over by LXQt.

### Details: a LXQt UI quirk

You can ignore the fact that, at the next start of `lxqt-config-locale`, your "Region: No change" value will be replaced with the system-wide locale value. This should be considered as a bug in LXQt in initializing this dialog. But as long as you don't save that dialog's values again, `~/.config/lxqt/lxqt-config-locale.conf` will still not overwrite the system-wide locale value.